# How to delete email field from Contacts via Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

```
function matchAndReplace(){
  var oldDomain = "@olddomain.com";
  var newDomain = "@newdomain.com";
  // retrieve all the user's contacts
  var contacts = ContactsApp.getContacts();
  Logger.log('num '+contacts.length);

  for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
    var emails = contacts[i].getEmails();
    Logger.log(emails.length+' emails');

    for (var e in emails) {
      var email = emails[e].getAddress();

      //emails[e].setLabel(ContactsApp.Field.WORK_EMAIL);
      Logger.log(email);

      if (email.indexOf(oldDomain) !== -1) {
        //remove
        emails[e].deleteEmailField(); <-- error
        Logger.log(email+' removed');
        //add
        var newEmail = email.split("@")[0]+newDomain;
        var newEmailField = contacts[i].addEmail(ContactsApp.Field.WORK_EMAIL, newEmail);
        Logger.log(newEmail+' added');
      }
    }
    //break;
  }
}
```

Error:

```
Service error: ContactsApp: Entry does not have any fields set. (line 20, file "Code")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be running into a transient service issue, because there's nothing obviously wrong with your code. You could improve its efficiency and eliminate all the delete / add operations, though, and that might reduce the possibility of the error.

Try this:

```
/**
 * Find all contacts that have email addresses in the oldDomain,
 * and change them to be the same ID in the newDomain.
 *
 * @param {String} oldDomain  E.g. 'oldExample.com'
 * @param {String} newDomain  E.g. 'newExample.org'
 *
 * @returns {Number}          Count of updated contacts.
 */
function migrateDomain(oldDomain, newDomain){
  // Validate arguments
  if (arguments.length !== 2) throw new Error( 'Missing arguments.');

  oldDomain = '@' + oldDomain;
  newDomain = '@' + newDomain;

  // retrieve all the user's contacts that have email in oldDomain
  var contacts = ContactsApp.getContactsByEmailAddress(oldDomain);
  Logger.log('num '+contacts.length);

  for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
    var emails = contacts[i].getEmails();
    Logger.log(emails.length+' emails');

    for (var e=0; e<emails.length; e++) {
      var email = emails[e].getAddress();

      Logger.log(email);

      if (email.indexOf(oldDomain) !== -1) {
        // change
        var newEmail = email.split("@")[0]+newDomain;
        emails[e].setAddress(newEmail);
        Logger.log(' changed to '+newEmail);
      }
    }
  }
  return i;
}
```

Comment: that worked perfectly! thank you. i think their names for Address() and Email() got me confused. cheers :)

Comment: I found that strange as well. It doesn't help that the documentation for `emailField.setAddress` has an example with street addresses!

Comment: @GianPaJ: I noticed that your edits to this answer were rejected, but shouldn't have been. (In comments, you should have said you were the question author AND that you were obfuscating personal info, that may have swayed reviewers.) Anyway, I've edited the code to make it more general now.